# NSFetchedResultsController crashes on every save operation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

Even when I commented out every single activity within the delegate methods, every time I call an "managedobjectcontext save:nil" operation, the app crashes with different erros namely the following: (seems like a release problem but not sure where.  I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

```
#0  0x02813a93 in objc_msgSend
#1  0xbfffd5b0 in ??
#2  0x0236c1b2 in -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _postprocessInsertedObjects:]
#3  0x023721bc in -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:]
#4  0x00024c1d in _nsnote_callback
#5  0x02690cf9 in __CFXNotificationPost_old
#6  0x0261011a in _CFXNotificationPostNotification
#7  0x0001a7c2 in -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]
#8  0x022ae519 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:]
#9  0x0231db33 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:withDeletions:withUpdates:withRefreshes:]
#10 0x02290f78 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:]
#11 0x022caa15 in -[NSManagedObjectContext save:]
#12 0x00005147 in -[PostsViewController saveMOC:] at PostsViewController.m:254
#13 0x00039e9a in __NSThreadPerformPerform
#14 0x02699d7f in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
#15 0x025f81dd in __CFRunLoopDoSources0
#16 0x025f77c6 in __CFRunLoopRun
#17 0x025f7280 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
#18 0x025f71a1 in CFRunLoopRunInMode
#19 0x02f1d2c8 in GSEventRunModal
#20 0x02f1d38d in GSEventRun
#21 0x002c8b58 in UIApplicationMain
#22 0x000028c0 in main at main.m:14
```

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have an attribute that changes the FRC when the context is saved. If you have a attribute used as `sectionNameKeyPath`, a change to the attribute upon save could trigger this problem.